# Difference of two sums

Tags: summation

A sequence $a_n$ is given such that $a_n \rightarrow 0\wedge a_n>0\ \forall n$.
I am to proof that
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}a_n - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n+1}a_n\right| \le a_{N+1}.$$
I found out that 
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}a_n - \sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n+1}a_n\right| = \left|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}a_n\right|,$$
but I don't know how to continue that proof.
I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

That is not true in general. Let $a_{2i - 1} = \frac1i$ and $a_{2i} = \frac1{2^i}$. Then
$$\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}a_n\right| = +\infty$$
for all $N$, because
$$\sum_{i = k}^{+\infty}a_{2i - 1} = \sum_{i = k}^{+\infty}\frac1i = +\infty$$
and
$$\sum_{i = \ell}^{+\infty}a_{2i} = \sum_{i = \ell}^{+\infty}\frac1{2^i} = \frac1{2^{\ell - 1}}.$$